# Grid Layouts in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have two grid rows which will vary in terms of the content of them.

I want the top row to have it's content centred vertically within than row.

And the bottom row aligned to the bottom vertically.

```
<Grid>     
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel>
                ...
            </StackPanel>                
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
         ...           
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is what it should look like.

```
  +-----------------------------+               +--------------------------------+
  |                             |               |                                |
  |                             |               |                                |
  |                             |               |                                |
  | Content Centered            |               |                                |
  |                             |               |                                |
  |                             |               | Content Centered               |
  |                             |               |                                |
  +-----------------------------+     or        |                                |
  |                             |               |                                |
  |                             |               |                                |
  |                             |               |                                |
  |                             |               +--------------------------------+
  |                             |               |                                |
  | Content at the bottom       |               | Content at the bottom          |
  +-----------------------------+               +--------------------------------+
```

The content of the rows can vary, I've used rowdefinitions at some point but it didn't work because I don't know a fixed height for either row.

Comment: Well, you need to define some `RowDefinitions` or you won't get far. Also, draw a god damn image, if you want help for layout.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions(v=vs.95).aspx for RowDefinition values, but you can have Auto and * as valus...they don't have to be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I said, `Grid.Row="1"` have no effect unless you use define a series of `RowDefinition` elements. Anyway, the issue you describe is easy enough,

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <!-- stuff here is center aligned -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <!-- stuff here is bottom aligned -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: VerticalContentAlignment doesn't exist. I'm developing for windows-phone 7

Comment: i guess he meant `VerticalAlignment`

Comment: No, I did not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.verticalcontentalignment(v=VS.95).aspx (it IS supported for Windows Phone, just not for the Grid element.)

Comment: i've added a row definition, so that i have a minimum height for the bottom row and the top row will fit auto.

Comment: do i have to add anything to the namespaces for `VerticalContentAlignment` to work?

Comment: Anyway, just align your content in the second row to the bottom?

Comment: `Grid` is not inherited from `Control`, that's why you don't see `VerticalContentAlignment` property in a `Grid`

Comment: Aligning to the bottom is fine, it's aligning the content inside the first row centrally that's not working.

Comment: Looks very much centered on my screen.